сборка libqpxx на Microsoft VS
Собрал библиотеку (используя MinGW, а не VS, возможно, проблема в этом), получил .dll файл, закинул его в проект, включил include папку из libpqxx, не входя в build, получил ошибку
1>D:\codes\libpqxx-7.9.2\include\pqxx\internal\header-pre.hxx(57,10): fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: pqxx/config-public-compiler.h: No such file or directory

в качестве кода использовал то, что написано в GetStarted, потом закинул в include 3 .h файла из build->include и выдало более сотни ошибок, вот пример из середины
1>D:\codes\libpqxx-7.9.2\include\pqxx\internal\encodings.hxx(146,3): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: (
1>D:\codes\libpqxx-7.9.2\include\pqxx\internal\encodings.hxx(146,1): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>D:\codes\libpqxx-7.9.2\include\pqxx\internal\encodings.hxx(146,1): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: )
1>D:\codes\libpqxx-7.9.2\include\pqxx\internal\encodings.hxx(146,3): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: )
1>D:\codes\libpqxx-7.9.2\include\pqxx\internal\encodings.hxx(146,1): warning C4183: __attribute__: отсутствие возвращаемого типа; предполагается функция-член, возвращающая "int"
1>D:\codes\libpqxx-7.9.2\include\pqxx\internal\encodings.hxx(161,1): error C2988: неопознанное объявление или определение шаблона
1>D:\codes\libpqxx-7.9.2\include\pqxx\internal\encodings.hxx(161,1): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: (

все указывают на файлы библиотеки, но внутри они не помечаются - вероятно, так как MSVS, как подключить libpqxx -загадка

Предпологаю, что последовательность такая: установить libpq, собрать libpqxx через cmake, затем сделать ей install в нужную директорию, полученные include/lib/dll добавить в проект... Ну либо сам проект на cmake сделать и подключить libpqxx как подпроект....

вариант №2: посмотреть в пакетных менеджерах - https://vcpkg.io/en/package/libpqxx, https://conan.io/center/recipes/libpqxx?version=7.9.2

Всё, решил, проблема была в attribute, оказалось, что у меня устаревшая SDK, которая не находит этот объект, обновил, заработало, всем ищущим спасибо
